# I want to add number in India currency format to the kendo grid column

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

In Kendo Grid Where I want to seperate amount in Indian Currency format for the number in angular js . for eg: 12345678= 1,23,45,678.00

Answer (score 0):

Here is two ways of doing it, base function to use is `toLocaleString()` which will parse it, refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) for more details.

Note: Use this filter inside the Kendo UI grid when displaying numbers!!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
 $scope.number = 123456789;
});
app.filter("custom", function(){
 return function(data){
   return data.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    {{number.toLocaleString('en-IN')}}
    <br>
    {{number | custom}}
</div>
```

Comment: @vikas Did this answer help you?

Comment: Thanks , i have used filter feature of kendo grid.

Comment: @vikasahire If this answer helped you completely, please close the question!